# Using Powershell to set an Excel Checkbox value

Tags: excel, powershell

I am creating a Talend job that runs an Excel Macro in an Excel Workbook. This is accomplished via Talend running powershell commands that open the existing spreadsheet.

In Order to run the macro, a checkbox on the form must be set to true. I have looked on the forums and some basic documentation, but have not found a solution that works for me.

For example, I found the following commands that open excel and create a checkbox. How would I set this new checkbox to true?

```
$missing = [System.Type]::missing
$excel = New-Object -Com Excel.Application
$wb = $excel.Workbooks.Add($missing)
$ws = $wb.Worksheets.Item(1)
$excel.Visible = $true
$oleObjects = $ws.OLEObjects($missing)
$checkbox = $oleObjects.Add("Forms.CheckBox.1",$missing,0,0,$missing,$missing,$missing,22.5,21,122.25,18.75)
```

Does anyone know of the answer, or a good tutorial that will show the commands needed to do this?

*I am doing this project as a favor, so learning the fundamentals of powershell are not needed at this time. I realize that I am skipping over the important step of learning Powershell first.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any tutorial for this specific use case.
You really cannot skip getting some training / reading on PowerShell and expect to do this as well as an understanding of the MS Excel Object model to interact with it.

I'll leave it at that and point you to these resources:

[Introducing the PowerShell Excel Module](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/11/25/introducing-the-powershell-excel-module-2)

[powershell-and-excels-form-controls](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/09e31365-2997-48ff-9e98-b01468ed805c/powershell-and-excels-form-controls)

[automating-excel-spreadsheets-with-powershell](https://posh2scripting.wordpress.com/2013/07/31/automating-excel-spreadsheets-with-powershell)

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to create a checkbox on a spreadsheet and set its value. I have not yet found out how to set the value of an existing checkbox, however.

```
$excel = new-object -comobject Excel.Application
$workbooks = $excel.Workbooks.Add()
$worksheets = $workbooks.worksheets
$worksheet = $worksheets.Item(1)
$worksheet.Name = “mine”
$excel.Visible = $True
$CheckBoxes = $worksheet.CheckBoxes()
$checkbox = $CheckBoxes.Add(1,1,1,1)
$checkbox.Value = 1
```